# How to cancel the keyboard in UISearchbar?

Tags: iphone, iphone-softkeyboard

I'm using `UISearchBar` in my application and it serves as both an edit field as well as a search.  So when I want to disappear the keyboard I have to use cancel button in UISearchBar but I can't have that cancel button on screen, so how could T make keyboard disappear when not used without using cancel button.  Please help me as i'm new to iPhone application development.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9):

Use this:

```
[UISearchBar resignFirstResponder];
```

Just replace the word UISearchBar with the name of the object you have created.

Comment: I thought I had this problem, but actually I needed to override disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal because I was using a UIModalPresentationPageSheet view.  Just mentioning it here in case others find this as hard to track down as I did.

Comment: Sorry, should have said UIModalPresentationFormSheet

Comment: Excellent comment @Bryan -- that was my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for ways you can dismiss the keyboard or how to actually do that programmatically? If programmatically, then `[UISearchBar resignFirstResponder]`. If you are looking for a possible way for the user to achieve that you can either make the return button on the keyboard resign its first responder status when pressed, or attach a `UIGestureRecognizer` to your view and set it up so that when the user clicks outside the keyboard, this keyboard goes away.

Answer (score 1):

simply all you need to do is to get UITextfield control from the UISearchbar and then set UITextfield's delegate to whatever delegate that will perform `-(void) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField`

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{    
    UIView * subView;
    NSArray * subViews = [searchbar subviews];
    for(subView in subViews)
    {
        if( [subView isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]] )
        {
           ((UITextField*)subView).delegate=self;
            ((UITextField*)subView).returnKeyType=UIReturnKeyDone;
            break;
        }
    }
}

-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return TRUE;
}
```